# MongoDB cluster is disconnected while trying to connect with C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, connection, cluster-computing

I am having some troubles connecting to MongoDB using URI in a Windows Service in .NET and using C#.

I have successfully connected to the database using mongobooster, so I copied the connection string and use it in the code.

I am using the following code:

```
public string connectionString = "mongodb://user:pass@host:27017?authSource=admin";

var client = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl(connectionString));

if (client.Cluster.Description.State.ToString() != "Disconnected")
{
  _database = client.GetDatabase("database_name");

  var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name");

}
```

I have also tried to connect without using `new MongoUrl(ConnectionString)` and the cluster is always disconnected.

Any clue why I am not able to connect to the database?

.NET version is 4.6 and mongoDB library is installed from NuGet with version 2.4.4